# What is this design pattern called?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, object-oriented-design

I have some code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents Record Locator class
/// </summary>
public class RecordLocator : IRecordLocator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The Record Locator string, for example: ZT8C4O
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="RecordLocator"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="recordLocator">The record locator string.</param>
    private RecordLocator(string recordLocator)
    {
        Name = recordLocator;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Parses the specified record locator.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="recordLocator">The record locator string.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IRecordLocator Parse(string recordLocator)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(recordLocator))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("recordLocator");

        if (recordLocator.Length != 6)
        throw new ArgumentException("recordLocator.Length != 6");

        return new RecordLocator(recordLocator);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Represents Record Locator interface
/// </summary>
public interface IRecordLocator : IHideObjectMembers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The Record Locator string, for example: ZT8C4O
    /// </summary>
    string Name { get; }
}
```

1. What is this design-pattern called? When you have a class, which instantiating itself (and probably have a private constructor)?
   Another example of this is `System.DateTime` class of .NET framework.
2. Is it OK to do it like that?

Comment: Lazy initialization?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a "name that thing" question. "Name that thing" are bad questions for the same reasons that "identify this obscure TV show, film or book by its characters or story" are bad questions: you can't Google them, they aren't practical in any way, they don't help anyone else, and allowing them opens the door for the asking of other types of marginal questions. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a [static factory pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929021/what-are-static-factory-methods-in-java). In this particular instance it doesn't currently provide anything that a traditional constructor couldn't(IE object pooling or multiple implementation types) so it doesn't add much value, but isn't wrong.

Comment: It does add something: it makes it clear that the parameter is *parsed*, which could make the code clearer (or more confusing if the parameter is not parsed, but just assigned to a property).

Answer (score 1):

Besides "static factory" (see Sign's answer), I have also heard the term "creation method". Creation methods have the advantage that they have a specific name that **conveys meaning**. You can also create several methods with the same parameter signature, e.g. an `Angle` struct with methods `static Angle FromDegrees(double degrees)` and `FromRadians(double radians)`. This is not possible with constructors.

Answer (score 0):

I can't recognize any established design patterns here. However, parsing a string to build an object is good, I have seen many examples in Java(my primary language) like `Integer.parseInt`.

You cannot have a constructor for parsing strings because if the parsing fails, you must throw an exception(expensive) or keep an object in undefined state(bad). Parsing method can either generate a new object or return null.

Comment: Returning null on failure is a bad idea. Using the TryXxx pattern (like e.g. int.TryParse) would be much better.

Comment: @svick I don't know about any tryParse in Java. I don't think null is a bad idea, exceptions are expensive.

Answer (score -3):

No such pattern exists in GoF book. Nor I heard about this kind of pattern.

Yes it is OK to do that. But be careful, because it limits extensibility.

Comment: I wouldn't be so quick to answer that something doesn't exist.